# Hibernate OneToMany subquery fails

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one

I have a one to many relation between two tables.
Here is the Many side of it:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_GLOBAL_USERS_AUTHORIZATION")
public class TGlobalUsersAuthorization{
  ....
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
  public TUserProfile getUserProfile() {
    return userProfile;
  }
}
```

When I fetch the One side entity i Get the following exception:
"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "GLOBALAUTH0_"."USERPROFILE": invalid identifier"
It looks like Hibernate sees the One side entity userProfile as a column in the table T_GLOBAL_USERS_AUTHORIZATION.

The One side entity is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_USER_PROFILE" )
public class TUserProfile implements Serializable {
... 
@OneToMany(targetEntity = TGlobalUsersAuthorization.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "userProfile")
@Cascade({ CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<TGlobalUsersAuthorization> globalAuthorizations;
```

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Kirill.

Comment: Try to remove this: 'targetEntity = TGlobalUsersAuthorization.class'. And what exactly cause this exception?

Comment: I've tested it, and it works at least with the current hibernate version. So either thats an already fixed bug or your failure is at a different location.